# How to make Netbeans open contextRoot on run?

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven, netbeans, ear

Using NetBeans 7.2.

I have an Enterprise Application packaged as a .EAR.

In the POM, I have set the context root as described here: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/examples/customizing-context-root.html to

```
/myapp
```

which by inspecting the application.xml that maven generates, it indeed gets set to this location (and I can browse to localhost:8080/myapp successfully).

However, when I 'Run' the .EAR in NetBeans it always opens

```
localhost:8080/myapp_war-1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

This page does not exist so I get a 404 and have to manually browse to the url.
I want it to open

```
localhost:8080/myapp
```

How do I make it do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched again today, and a bug has recently been filed. So I don't believe there is a way around this at the moment.

http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=221541